# Есть ли Code Style в Visual Studio Code?

Tags: style, code-style

Есть ли дополнение или встроенная функция Code Style с горячими клавишами в  Visual Studio Code?

В pyCharm это комбинация Ctrl + Alt + L. Есть такое в  Visual Studio Code? В расширениях искал, не смог найти.

Comment: [Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)

Comment: Судя по всему тебе нужен: `Shift+Alt+F` _Format Document_

Comment: Не работает такое сочетание. Пишет:
Neither a pharPath or use of Composer was specified. Aborting...

Comment: [Neither a pharPath or use of Composer was specified](https://github.com/Dickurt/vscode-php-formatter/issues/17)

Answer (score 2):

В **Visual Studio Code** уже встроена функция форматирование кода.

`Format Document` - `Ctrl+Shift+I`

`Format Selection` - `Ctrl+K Ctrl+F`

Также, по желанию их можно переназначить в `File > Preferences > Keyboards Shortcuts` или же нажав `Ctrl+K Ctrl+S`

Answer (score 0):

Если речь о MS Visual Studio, то когда-то я пользовался такими сочетаниями:

- `Ctrl+K,D` — форматировать весь документ в соответствии с правилами, заданными в настройках.
- `Ctrl+K,F` — форматировать выделенный текст.

P.S. это я отрыл случайно, тыкая на разные сочетания клавиш. Справку по HotKey не нашел.

Comment: [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) - это не студия, а легкий редактор